# Incorrect capitalization of "MathJax" on Ask Question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, spelling

I noticed that *MathJax* is incorrectly capitalized on the [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page, in two places. It should be **[MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/#about)**, not **MathJaX**.

Screenshot (from another post):

[image: mathjax]

Comment: Whose idea was it to have capital letters in the middle of words, anyway?

Comment: @GerryMyerson They probably were inspired by the spelling of LaTeX, so it was Lamport, I guess. (Like LaTeX is a combination of La(mport) and TeX, MathJax is a combination of Math(ematics) and (a)Jax, so it kinda makes sense.)

Comment: This should be fixed. I know mods can edit some special areas, but I don't know if they can edit the Ask Question page – we might need to contact Stack Exchange to ask them to change it.

Comment: @wythagoras Moderators cannot edit that page/sidebar. It'll have to be done by an employee. But this change should be made for all MathJax-enabled SE sites, which have the same text, but instead link to [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/). SE does keep tabs on child-meta bug reports, and if a change doesn't happen within some reasonable time, one of the mods can ping a CM. (FWIW, 1999 is likely able to get Shog's attention in the Tavern fairly frequently.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed, and will apply as of build 2863.

Comment: Just to be certain, this fix will apply to all MathJax-enabled sites?

Comment: Yes, the changes are not site-specific.